# spring MVC form action not adding project name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on sample spring MVC applicaiton. created My issue is in form i mapped action to some method , but after submitting form it removes the project name and request is just becomes like: localhost:8080/addUser rather than localhost:8080/myproject/addUser

Required details :
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.sachin.canbank.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sachin.canbank.model.User;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUser(){
        return new User();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        return null;
    }

}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form  action="/addUser" commandName="user" method="POST">
    <form:input path="username"/>
    <form:input path="password" />
    <form:input path="email" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either remove the `/` or use a `<c:url />` or `<spring:url />` tag to calculate the URL.

Comment: by simply removing / it didnt work. but with <c:url /> it did work. But why previously it did not work,  as on multiple online tutorial they didnt used c:url

Comment: Using a `/` means it is from the root of the URL. It would work if your application is deployed on root i.e. `/` but yours isn't. You could also leave the action it will then submit to the URL used to retrieve the form.