# Spring MVN Controller works in GET but does not in POST

Tags: spring-mvc, post, get

I have this simple Controller

```html
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

 private ModelAndView model;
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/loginUser/{username}/{password}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView loginUser(@PathVariable(value="username") String username, @PathVariable(value="password") String password) {
  try {
  
          if( checkCredential( username , password ) ) {
   model = new LoginResult( "loginOK" );
   model.addObject( "msg" , username );
   
  } else {
   model = new LoginResult( "loginKO" );
   model.addObject( "msg" , "Impossible to login the user " + username );
   
  }
  
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return model;
  
 }

}
```

and this simple JSP to execute the login

```html
<form method="get" action="/login/loginUser">
      <div class="div-top-end-space">&nbsp;</div>
      <div>
       <label class="form-label"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1"></i> USERNAME:</label>
       <input class="form-input" type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" /> 
      </div>
      <div>
       <label class="form-label"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1"></i> PASSWORD:</label>
       <input class="form-input" type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" />
      </div>
      <div class="div-separator"></div>
      <div>
       <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" ng-disabled="checkCredential()"/>
      </div>
      <div class="div-top-end-space">&nbsp;</div>
     </form>
```

This code works properly, but I have to put into the URL
http://localhost:9001/MY_APP/login/loginUser/aaa/bbb

But I do not want that username and password are shown into the browser's URL.
So I change the method into the form in method="post" and into the controller, method="RequestMethod.POST".
When I run my application and I insert my username and password, it does not work, and into the URL I see this

http://localhost:9001/login/loginUser

1. Where did my application's name go???
2. How I can solve it?

Thanks to everybody.

Daniele.

Comment: is there any exception on submit?

Comment: you can add the appname yourself. maybe not the best solution though. `action="/AppName/login/loginUser"`

Comment: check the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543457/spring-mvc-form-action-not-adding-project-name

Comment: No, I do not have any exception on submit. I even think that my POST request is not sent to the server. But what I do not understand is why with GET is working perfectly. I can do all my system in GET, but the login...